# How to get POST Data on Best Practice CRUD (Update)

Tags: sapui5, hana

We want to update / edit the Data of a Customer. So we've tried out the original Code from the examples. The example works fine, but we usually have to check the Userinputs before we write that to the Database. Here's my Code:

```
    /**
     * Event handler (attached declaratively) for the view save button. Saves the changes added by the user.
     * @function
     * @public
     */
    onSave: function() {
        var that = this,
            oModel = this.getModel();

        // abort if the  model has not been changed
        if (!oModel.hasPendingChanges()) {
            MessageBox.information(
                this._oResourceBundle.getText("keine Änderungen"), {
                    id: "noChangesInfoMessageBox",
                    styleClass: that.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass()
                }
            );
            return;
        }
        this.getModel("appView").setProperty("/busy", true);
        if (this._oViewModel.getProperty("/mode") === "edit") {
            // attach to the request completed event of the batch
            oModel.attachEventOnce("batchRequestCompleted", function(oEvent) {
                var oParams = oEvent.getParameters();
                if (oParams.success) {
                    that._fnUpdateSuccess();
                } else {
                    that._fnEntityCreationFailed();
                }
            });
        }
        oModel.submitChanges();
    },
```

How may I access to the REQUEST Data ? I've tried to look at the oModel DOM, but only found `aBindings` where a lot of unuseful Stuff is there. Even `window.location.search` wasn't the solution.

Comment: Although you already answered your question.. do you need the data to sanitize/validate it **before** uploading it to your backend?

Comment: yes, we need to sanitize it before uploading. we already found a nice class to do so: [UI5 Validator](https://github.com/qualiture/ui5-validator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've fixed it.

Just use `this._getFormFields(this.byId("newEntitySimpleForm"));`